# Subtract data from two table to get total

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to find out total pending payment of customer. I have two tables: 1 is for invoices and 2nd is for received payments.

Here is the schema of invoice table

```
inv_no  |  date |  customer_name | total_baic | freight_rate | delivery_rate
```

and here is the schema of payment table

```
id | date | customer_name | payment_received | inv_no
```

What I need is pending customer wise like customer_name, total pending where total pending is (total_basic + freight_rate + delivery_rate) - (payment_received)

What I have tried is getting both differently but don't know how to do this subtraction part

Here is the query of pending from invoice table

```
SELECT Sum(invoice.freight_rate) + sum(invoice.total_basic_amount) + sum(invoice.delivery_rate) + sum(invoice.advanced_amount) AS totalpending FROM invoice GROUP BY invoice.client_name
```

Here is the query of payment recevide from payments table

```
SELECT Sum(payments.payment_received) AS totalreceived FROM payments GROUP BY payments.client_name
```

How to do substration of both like totalpending - totalreceived.

Somehow I'm able to create this query but problem is this query return double amount please can you chekc

```
**SELECT invoice.client_name, Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate) AS totalpending, Sum(payments.payment_received) AS totalpayment FROM invoice, payments GROUP BY invoice.client_name, payments.client_name**
```

I'm getting

```
client_name | totalpending | totalpayment
John | 1800 | 1100
```

Here total payment is correct coz in my payment table there is two entry one is for 600 and another for 500 so it's 1100
but in invoice table there is only one entry where total basic = 600 and freight rate =0 deliverrate also 0
so here totalpending has to be 600

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Need to include client_name in the SELECT clause (really should save ClientID in these tables, not names). Then join both queries to Clients table. Is the field client_name or customer_name?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this might be the solution you are looking for:

```
select invoice.customer_name, (sum(invoice.freight_rate) + sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+ sum(invoice.delivery_rate) - sum(payments.payment_received)) as TotalPending
from invoice,payments where invoice.inv_no=payments.inv_no
```

This query will get you the customer names and their total pending payments.

Comment: I have edited question please can you check

Comment: Can you please share the results and desired results as well? I don't quite understand what you mean by 'Double amount'.

Comment: question edited with output I get and expected

Comment: SELECT invoice.client_name, Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate) -Sum(payments.payment_received) AS totalpending, Sum(payments.payment_received) AS totalpayment FROM invoice, payments GROUP BY invoice.client_name, payments.client_name

Try this

Comment: This works but still I got totalpending 700 instead of 600

Comment: Actually this query is doing this: 

your pending total is 1800 and your payment total is 1100, so it is just subtracting these two, 1800-1100=700.

Comment: Okk I got it I got it Thanks alot .

Comment: There is some issue in this query It returns some thing weired amount can You help me to join this two query with - 1.) SELECT client_name, Sum(invoice.freight_rate) + sum(invoice.total_basic_amount) + sum(invoice.delivery_rate) AS totalpending FROM invoice GROUP BY invoice.client_name 2.)SELECT client_name, Sum(payments.payment_received) as total_payments FROM payments GROUP BY payments.client_name. I want to do client_name, totalpending - totalpayments

Comment: SELECT invoice.client_name, (Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate) -Sum(payments.payment_received))
 FROM invoice, payments GROUP BY invoice.client_name

Comment: still the same issue it has to be 3630 - 2500 = 1130 but I don't know Why it returns -14480

Comment: Sorry I forogt the where clause. Here is the query :

SELECT invoice.client_name, (Sum(invoice.freight_rate)+Sum(invoice.total_basic_amount)+Sum(invoice.delivery_rate) -Sum(payments.payment_received)) FROM invoice, payments where invoice.inv_no=payments.inv_no GROUP BY invoice.client_name

Comment: Hi this query is doubling first entry the real amount is 2500 but it shwos 5000 for the first entry. please can you check it out